# XML to XML using a XSL transform to Sort

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, asp-classic

I'm using the following XML, weather sensor structure.  The immediate goal is to sort this structure, first by sensor location and then by reading label.  I am a struggling newbie with XML processing!!!

```
<Sensors>
    <sensor location="House - Front Entry">
        <reading label="Temperature">
            <title>House - Front Entry</title>
            <label>Temperature</label>
            <value>57</value>
            <units>F</units>
            <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:49 PM</lastUpdate>
            <records>
                <record timeFrame="Today">
                    <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
                    <hi>64</hi>
                    <lo>56</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Week">
                    <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
                    <hi>72</hi>
                    <lo>46</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Month">
                    <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
                    <hi>79</hi>
                    <lo>46</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Year">
                    <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
                    <hi>80</hi>
                    <lo>41</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Alltime">
                    <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
                    <hi>80</hi>
                    <lo>41</lo>
                </record>
            </records>
        </reading>
        <reading label="Humidity">
            <title>House - Front Entry</title>
            <label>Humidity</label>
            <value>83</value>
            <units>%</units>
            <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:49 PM</lastUpdate>
            <records>
                <record timeFrame="Today">
                    <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
                    <hi>83</hi>
                    <lo>58</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Week">
                    <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
                    <hi>83</hi>
                    <lo>42</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Month">
                    <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>31</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Year">
                    <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>31</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Alltime">
                    <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>31</lo>
                </record>
            </records>
        </reading>
    </sensor>
    <sensor location="House - Patio">
        <reading label="Temperature">
            <title>House - Patio</title>
            <label>Temperature</label>
            <value>53</value>
            <units>F</units>
            <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:48 PM</lastUpdate>
            <records>
                <record timeFrame="Today">
                    <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
                    <hi>65</hi>
                    <lo>51</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Week">
                    <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
                    <hi>71</hi>
                    <lo>38</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Month">
                    <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
                    <hi>80</hi>
                    <lo>38</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Year">
                    <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
                    <hi>80</hi>
                    <lo>38</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Alltime">
                    <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
                    <hi>80</hi>
                    <lo>38</lo>
                </record>
            </records>
        </reading>
        <reading label="Humidity">
            <title>House - Patio</title>
            <label>Humidity</label>
            <value>98</value>
            <units>%</units>
            <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:48 PM</lastUpdate>
            <records>
                <record timeFrame="Today">
                    <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>47</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Week">
                    <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>33</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Month">
                    <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>24</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Year">
                    <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>24</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Alltime">
                    <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>24</lo>
                </record>
            </records>
        </reading>
        <reading label="Rainfall">
            <title>House - Patio</title>
            <label>Rainfall</label>
            <value>0.22</value>
            <units>in</units>
            <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:49 PM</lastUpdate>
            <records>
                <record timeFrame="Previous Event">
                    <timeFrame>Previous Event</timeFrame>
                    <total>0.24</total>
                    <eventDate>05/22/2013</eventDate>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Week">
                    <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
                    <total>0.22</total>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Month">
                    <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
                    <total>6.97</total>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Year">
                    <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
                    <total>6.97</total>
                </record>
            </records>
        </reading>
    </sensor>

    <sensor location="Cabin - Kitchen">
        <reading label="Temperature">
            <title>Cabin - Kitchen</title>
            <label>Temperature</label>
            <value>57</value>
            <units>F</units>
            <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 11:29 AM</lastUpdate>
            <records>
                <record timeFrame="Today">
                    <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
                    <hi>63</hi>
                    <lo>58</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Week">
                    <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
                    <hi>74</hi>
                    <lo>58</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Month">
                    <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
                    <hi>74</hi>
                    <lo>38</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Year">
                    <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
                    <hi>76</hi>
                    <lo>30</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Alltime">
                    <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
                    <hi>76</hi>
                    <lo>30</lo>
                </record>
            </records>
        </reading>
        <reading label="Humidity">
            <title>Cabin - Kitchen</title>
            <label>Humidity</label>
            <value>41</value>
            <units>%</units>
            <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 11:29 AM</lastUpdate>
            <records>
                <record timeFrame="Today">
                    <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
                    <hi>41</hi>
                    <lo>40</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Week">
                    <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
                    <hi>48</hi>
                    <lo>40</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Month">
                    <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
                    <hi>48</hi>
                    <lo>39</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Year">
                    <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
                    <hi>48</hi>
                    <lo>13</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Alltime">
                    <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
                    <hi>48</hi>
                    <lo>13</lo>
                </record>
            </records>
        </reading>
    </sensor>
</Sensors>
```

OK, the above is the XLM and below is my best try to create a XSL transform file.  I want the resulting output to be in XML format, exactly the same as the input file but sorted in A-Z order by the sensor "location" and reading "Label".  After lots of reading and Google searching this is what I have come up:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Sensors">
      <xsl:copy>    
    <xsl:apply-templates>
      <xsl:sort select="sensor/@location"/>
      <xsl:sort select="reading/label"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>     
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm using the Microsoft XML editor to test my code.  First off the output does not seem to have the XML structure of the input file and also it is not complete, sensor location and other items at the level and above are missing.

What am I doing wrong?

By the way, after I get this figured out I will be processing the complete XML file using the XSL transform file in classic ASP.  Most of that is already working, except of course the sorting process.

Answer (score 1):

Start with an [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and then override the parents of the elements you want sorted. You can use `sort` in `xsl:apply-templates` to sort.

**XML Input**

```
<Sensors>
    <sensor location="House - Front Entry">
        <reading label="Temperature">
            <title>House - Front Entry</title>
            <label>Temperature</label>
            <value>57</value>
            <units>F</units>
            <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:49 PM</lastUpdate>
            <records>
                <record timeFrame="Today">
                    <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
                    <hi>64</hi>
                    <lo>56</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Week">
                    <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
                    <hi>72</hi>
                    <lo>46</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Month">
                    <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
                    <hi>79</hi>
                    <lo>46</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Year">
                    <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
                    <hi>80</hi>
                    <lo>41</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Alltime">
                    <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
                    <hi>80</hi>
                    <lo>41</lo>
                </record>
            </records>
        </reading>
        <reading label="Humidity">
            <title>House - Front Entry</title>
            <label>Humidity</label>
            <value>83</value>
            <units>%</units>
            <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:49 PM</lastUpdate>
            <records>
                <record timeFrame="Today">
                    <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
                    <hi>83</hi>
                    <lo>58</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Week">
                    <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
                    <hi>83</hi>
                    <lo>42</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Month">
                    <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>31</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Year">
                    <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>31</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Alltime">
                    <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>31</lo>
                </record>
            </records>
        </reading>
    </sensor>
    <sensor location="House - Patio">
        <reading label="Temperature">
            <title>House - Patio</title>
            <label>Temperature</label>
            <value>53</value>
            <units>F</units>
            <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:48 PM</lastUpdate>
            <records>
                <record timeFrame="Today">
                    <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
                    <hi>65</hi>
                    <lo>51</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Week">
                    <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
                    <hi>71</hi>
                    <lo>38</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Month">
                    <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
                    <hi>80</hi>
                    <lo>38</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Year">
                    <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
                    <hi>80</hi>
                    <lo>38</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Alltime">
                    <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
                    <hi>80</hi>
                    <lo>38</lo>
                </record>
            </records>
        </reading>
        <reading label="Humidity">
            <title>House - Patio</title>
            <label>Humidity</label>
            <value>98</value>
            <units>%</units>
            <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:48 PM</lastUpdate>
            <records>
                <record timeFrame="Today">
                    <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>47</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Week">
                    <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>33</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Month">
                    <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>24</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Year">
                    <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>24</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Alltime">
                    <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
                    <hi>99</hi>
                    <lo>24</lo>
                </record>
            </records>
        </reading>
        <reading label="Rainfall">
            <title>House - Patio</title>
            <label>Rainfall</label>
            <value>0.22</value>
            <units>in</units>
            <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:49 PM</lastUpdate>
            <records>
                <record timeFrame="Previous Event">
                    <timeFrame>Previous Event</timeFrame>
                    <total>0.24</total>
                    <eventDate>05/22/2013</eventDate>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Week">
                    <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
                    <total>0.22</total>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Month">
                    <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
                    <total>6.97</total>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Year">
                    <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
                    <total>6.97</total>
                </record>
            </records>
        </reading>
    </sensor>

    <sensor location="Cabin - Kitchen">
        <reading label="Temperature">
            <title>Cabin - Kitchen</title>
            <label>Temperature</label>
            <value>57</value>
            <units>F</units>
            <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 11:29 AM</lastUpdate>
            <records>
                <record timeFrame="Today">
                    <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
                    <hi>63</hi>
                    <lo>58</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Week">
                    <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
                    <hi>74</hi>
                    <lo>58</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Month">
                    <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
                    <hi>74</hi>
                    <lo>38</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Year">
                    <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
                    <hi>76</hi>
                    <lo>30</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Alltime">
                    <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
                    <hi>76</hi>
                    <lo>30</lo>
                </record>
            </records>
        </reading>
        <reading label="Humidity">
            <title>Cabin - Kitchen</title>
            <label>Humidity</label>
            <value>41</value>
            <units>%</units>
            <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 11:29 AM</lastUpdate>
            <records>
                <record timeFrame="Today">
                    <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
                    <hi>41</hi>
                    <lo>40</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Week">
                    <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
                    <hi>48</hi>
                    <lo>40</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Month">
                    <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
                    <hi>48</hi>
                    <lo>39</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Year">
                    <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
                    <hi>48</hi>
                    <lo>13</lo>
                </record>
                <record timeFrame="Alltime">
                    <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
                    <hi>48</hi>
                    <lo>13</lo>
                </record>
            </records>
        </reading>
    </sensor>
</Sensors>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Sensors">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:sort select="@location"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sensor">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
                <xsl:sort select="@label"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>     
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Sensors>
   <sensor location="Cabin - Kitchen">
      <reading label="Humidity">
         <title>Cabin - Kitchen</title>
         <label>Humidity</label>
         <value>41</value>
         <units>%</units>
         <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 11:29 AM</lastUpdate>
         <records>
            <record timeFrame="Today">
               <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
               <hi>41</hi>
               <lo>40</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Week">
               <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
               <hi>48</hi>
               <lo>40</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Month">
               <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
               <hi>48</hi>
               <lo>39</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Year">
               <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
               <hi>48</hi>
               <lo>13</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Alltime">
               <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
               <hi>48</hi>
               <lo>13</lo>
            </record>
         </records>
      </reading>
      <reading label="Temperature">
         <title>Cabin - Kitchen</title>
         <label>Temperature</label>
         <value>57</value>
         <units>F</units>
         <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 11:29 AM</lastUpdate>
         <records>
            <record timeFrame="Today">
               <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
               <hi>63</hi>
               <lo>58</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Week">
               <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
               <hi>74</hi>
               <lo>58</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Month">
               <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
               <hi>74</hi>
               <lo>38</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Year">
               <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
               <hi>76</hi>
               <lo>30</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Alltime">
               <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
               <hi>76</hi>
               <lo>30</lo>
            </record>
         </records>
      </reading>
   </sensor>
   <sensor location="House - Front Entry">
      <reading label="Humidity">
         <title>House - Front Entry</title>
         <label>Humidity</label>
         <value>83</value>
         <units>%</units>
         <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:49 PM</lastUpdate>
         <records>
            <record timeFrame="Today">
               <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
               <hi>83</hi>
               <lo>58</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Week">
               <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
               <hi>83</hi>
               <lo>42</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Month">
               <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
               <hi>99</hi>
               <lo>31</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Year">
               <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
               <hi>99</hi>
               <lo>31</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Alltime">
               <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
               <hi>99</hi>
               <lo>31</lo>
            </record>
         </records>
      </reading>
      <reading label="Temperature">
         <title>House - Front Entry</title>
         <label>Temperature</label>
         <value>57</value>
         <units>F</units>
         <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:49 PM</lastUpdate>
         <records>
            <record timeFrame="Today">
               <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
               <hi>64</hi>
               <lo>56</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Week">
               <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
               <hi>72</hi>
               <lo>46</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Month">
               <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
               <hi>79</hi>
               <lo>46</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Year">
               <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
               <hi>80</hi>
               <lo>41</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Alltime">
               <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
               <hi>80</hi>
               <lo>41</lo>
            </record>
         </records>
      </reading>
   </sensor>
   <sensor location="House - Patio">
      <reading label="Humidity">
         <title>House - Patio</title>
         <label>Humidity</label>
         <value>98</value>
         <units>%</units>
         <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:48 PM</lastUpdate>
         <records>
            <record timeFrame="Today">
               <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
               <hi>99</hi>
               <lo>47</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Week">
               <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
               <hi>99</hi>
               <lo>33</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Month">
               <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
               <hi>99</hi>
               <lo>24</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Year">
               <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
               <hi>99</hi>
               <lo>24</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Alltime">
               <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
               <hi>99</hi>
               <lo>24</lo>
            </record>
         </records>
      </reading>
      <reading label="Rainfall">
         <title>House - Patio</title>
         <label>Rainfall</label>
         <value>0.22</value>
         <units>in</units>
         <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:49 PM</lastUpdate>
         <records>
            <record timeFrame="Previous Event">
               <timeFrame>Previous Event</timeFrame>
               <total>0.24</total>
               <eventDate>05/22/2013</eventDate>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Week">
               <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
               <total>0.22</total>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Month">
               <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
               <total>6.97</total>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Year">
               <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
               <total>6.97</total>
            </record>
         </records>
      </reading>
      <reading label="Temperature">
         <title>House - Patio</title>
         <label>Temperature</label>
         <value>53</value>
         <units>F</units>
         <lastUpdate>05/28/2013 09:48 PM</lastUpdate>
         <records>
            <record timeFrame="Today">
               <timeFrame>Today</timeFrame>
               <hi>65</hi>
               <lo>51</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Week">
               <timeFrame>Week</timeFrame>
               <hi>71</hi>
               <lo>38</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Month">
               <timeFrame>Month</timeFrame>
               <hi>80</hi>
               <lo>38</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Year">
               <timeFrame>Year</timeFrame>
               <hi>80</hi>
               <lo>38</lo>
            </record>
            <record timeFrame="Alltime">
               <timeFrame>Alltime</timeFrame>
               <hi>80</hi>
               <lo>38</lo>
            </record>
         </records>
      </reading>
   </sensor>
</Sensors>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Sensors" >
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="sensor">
                <xsl:sort select="@location"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="sensor">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="reading">
                <xsl:sort select="@label"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```